# QCombobox with model with 50,000 rows has large delay on the first-time dropdown

Tags: qt, model, qcombobox, large-data

When assigning prepared model having more than 50,000 rows (which performs immediately) to a combobox and trying to press dropdown button, experience a few seconds delay before combobox dropdown list appear. Observe this situation ONLY when FIRST time presses dropdown button in combobox.

Any way to improve performance here?

Comment: Maybe first reconsider your GUI design? How can this huge combo box used with 50K items?

Comment: Simply :) When it loads first time it works VERY fast, just fine even with 100k rows in it. With QCompleter it does everything we need very comfortable. User should select a value ONLY from a predefined value set which is big, medications list, for example. Common situation.

Comment: Post a sample code constructing this combo using a model that reproduces the delay. What model are you using?

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see which function spends most time? Try breaking randomly during the delay (F12 on Visual Studio, or assign a shortcut in Qt Creator to Debug->Break).

Comment: QStandardItemModel. Code for model loading:
`void MyDialog::loadValueSet()
{
  QList<MyType> list = AllergyDB::getList(myDatabase);

  myModel = new QStandardItemModel();
  foreach (MyType type, list) {
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(type.name);
    item->setData(type.code, Qt::UserRole);
    myModel->appendRow(item);
  }
}`
Probably makes sense to load data directly to model from DB avoiding  intermediary list. But it is not a bottleneck as it loads in background - QFuture.

Comment: As I said delay observed when I press dropdown button in combobox, only on first press, after that it works very fast. Current index or model also switched immediately. `myComboBox->setModel(myModel)`. Probably solution is to switch to Qt 5.x which is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is combobox by default uses `QStandardItemModel` to store the items and a `QListView` subclass displays the popuplist. Investigating `QListView` properties had solved the problem, details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404207/630169