# QCombobox works very slow with QSqlQueryModel with large model

Tags: performance, model-view-controller, qt4, qcombobox

I have few comboboxes with very dig data sets within ~ 100K rows and more. I tried it with `QStandardItemModel` - works fast enough if model is preloaded, also model loading takes few seconds if performed in separate thread. Tried comboboxes with `QSqlQueryModel` without threading to improve performance but experienced it works much slower than `QStandardItemModel` (in our project `QSqlQueryModel` works very fast with such amount of data with `QTreeView` for example). What could be the problem here? Is there a way to speed-up combobox, some parameters?

P.S. Suggested by Qt doc `QComboBox::AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon` does not speed things much: dialog with such combos starts too long and exits 10-20 sec. `AdjustToMinimumContentsLength` works a little bit faster but anyway delays are too long.

Comment: Do you really need a combobox with so many items?

Comment: Yes, user should select an item from predefined values: some of EMR value sets - medical app with about 100k problems list.

Comment: Could the problem be in single QSqlDatabase object for all the models? Should I use separate QSqlDatabase instances for each QSqlQueryModel?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think QComboBox creates all the data views even when they're not shown.

Comment: Paul-Sebastian, You can find **full** solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33454284/630169

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. 1st thought was to find what model will work faster, for example `QStringListModel` to replace `QStandardItemModel` or `QSqlQueryModel`. However seems that they work almost same speed. 2nd I found in Qt doc that combobox by default uses `QStandardItemModel` to store the items and a `QListView` subclass displays the popuplist. You can access the model and view directly (with `model()` and `view()`). That was strange for me as I know `QTreeView` works just fine with even bigger amount of data, and simpler `QListView` also inherited from `QAbstractItemView` should do this as well. I start to digg into `QListView` and found properties in it which had solved the problem: now combobox opens immediately on large amount of data. Static function was written to tweak all of such combos (comments with explanation are from Qt doc):

```
void ComboboxTools::tweak(QComboBox *combo)
{
  //  For performance reasons use this policy on large models
  // or AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon
  combo->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToMinimumContentsLength);

  QListView *view = (QListView *)combo->view();
  // Improving Performance:  It is possible to give the view hints
  // about the data it is handling in order to improve its performance
  // when displaying large numbers of items. One approach that can be taken
  // for views that are intended to display items with equal sizes
  // is to set the uniformItemSizes property to true.
  view->setUniformItemSizes(true);
  // This property holds the layout mode for the items. When the mode is Batched,
  // the items are laid out in batches of batchSize items, while processing events.
  // This makes it possible to instantly view and interact with the visible items
  // while the rest are being laid out.
  view->setLayoutMode(QListView::Batched);
  // batchSize : int
  // This property holds the number of items laid out in each batch
  // if layoutMode is set to Batched. The default value is 100.
}
```

Comment: Only a question remained: how to speed-up the completer or let it open after 2nd or 3rd input character?

Comment: **Full** solution for this situation could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33454284/630169