# QCompleter for large models

Tags: qt, model, qcompleter, large-data

`QCompleter` works slightly slow on large data sets (large models): when I start to input characters in `QCombobox` it passes few seconds to show auto-complete popup with variants, when input 2nd char `QCompleter` does not react on key press for few seconds as well. Next characters works fine. Model size is about 100K records. Is it possible to improve `QCompleter` performance or show popup after 2nd or 3rd input symbol? Are there some good examples?

Comment: What model do you use? Possible, you need to improve performance of your model.

Comment: I use `QStandardItemModel`. How to improve its performance? I tried to presort it, to setup sensitivity like Qt doc says: `combo->completer()->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
  combo->completer()->setModelSorting(QCompleter::CaseSensitivelySortedModel);`

What else can I do?

Comment: You can create your own model, based on `QAbstractItemModel`.

Comment: Two helpful links for you: http://habrahabr.ru/post/171443/ http://habrahabr.ru/post/172187/

Comment: No, `QStandardItemModel` is good enough here, look at the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution appears similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404207/630169 as `QCompleter` also uses `QListView` in its `popup()`. So **full** solution to speed-up QCombobox is:

## Tweak combo:

```
void ComboboxTools::tweak(QComboBox *combo)
{
  //  For performance reasons use this policy on large models
  // or AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon
  combo->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToMinimumContentsLength);

  // Improve combobox view performance
  tweak((QListView *)combo->view());

  // Improve combobox completer performance
  tweak(combo->completer());
}
```

## Tweak dropdown/popup (view):

```
void ComboboxTools::tweak(QListView *view)
{
  // Improving Performance:  It is possible to give the view hints
  // about the data it is handling in order to improve its performance
  // when displaying large numbers of items. One approach that can be taken
  // for views that are intended to display items with equal sizes
  // is to set the uniformItemSizes property to true.
  view->setUniformItemSizes(true);
  // This property holds the layout mode for the items. When the mode is Batched,
  // the items are laid out in batches of batchSize items, while processing events.
  // This makes it possible to instantly view and interact with the visible items
  // while the rest are being laid out.
  view->setLayoutMode(QListView::Batched);
  // batchSize : int
  // This property holds the number of items laid out in each batch
  // if layoutMode is set to Batched. The default value is 100.
  // view->setBatchSize(100);
}
```

## Tweak completer:

```
void ComboboxTools::tweak(QCompleter *completer)
{
  completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
  // If the model's data for the completionColumn() and completionRole() is sorted
  // in ascending order, you can set ModelSorting property
  // to CaseSensitivelySortedModel or CaseInsensitivelySortedModel.
  // On large models, this can lead to significant performance improvements
  // because the completer object can then use a binary search algorithm
  // instead of linear search algorithm.
  completer->setModelSorting(QCompleter::CaseSensitivelySortedModel);

  // Improve completer popup (view) performance
  tweak((QListView *)completer->popup());
}
```