# How do i optimise performance of QCompleter?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have initialized QCompleter with QStringList. And this stringlist has more than 30,000 entries. I have connected to Qlineedit in my ui. No issues there. The problem lies in, whenever i type something in that qlineedit, as you may guess it the suggestion pop up very slow, as there are more than 30,000 entries. So i was wondering if is there any other method to improve the performance? like by using multithread or something like that. I am newbie to qt, I apologise if i made any error in implementing. Thank you

Edit:
My problem differs from this question [QCompleter for large models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447843/qcompleter-for-large-models) as i am not using QComboBox, i am using QLineEdit.

Comment: You might re-consider using line edit for such a huge string.

Comment: Individual Strings are not huge, but the number of strings are more in the QStringList.

Comment: [QCompleter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) use a [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html). So you can implement your own model to improve performance

Comment: Ok i will try that

Comment: It was my first thought that custom model could be used but it's quite unlikely that it can really help here because `QCompleter` would in either case do either linear scan through the model's indexes or binary search. There's no single "find in model" method to override for the custom model so it doesn't really seem possible to achieve much by introducing the custom model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QCompleter for large models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447843/qcompleter-for-large-models)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you could try is using sorted `QStringList` instead of unsorted one. I don't know where you take the strings for your list but if you can get them in sorted order instead of unsorted one, you should definitely try it. Then you'd be able to call [setModelSorting](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#modelSorting-prop) method on the completer with  `QCompleter::CaseSensitivelySortedModel` or `QCompleter::CaseInsensitivelySortedModel` value - that would allow your completer to switch from [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) (O(n) complexity) to [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (O(log(n)) complexity). Given your size of the string list, binary search in the worst case would require 11 comparisons (log(30000) ~= 10.3) to find the particular string while linear search would require 30000 comparisons in the worst case.

It might be that this suggestion won't work for you because you can't get your data in sorted order within the string list (or into any other data structure represented by any custom `QAbstractItemModel` subclass). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like `QCompleter` is easily extensible since its `setCompletionPrefix` method which seems to trigger the search for completions within the model is not virtual so you can't override it to work polymorphically. You might need to customize the widget for which you are attempting to use the completer so that it uses custom completion logic with efficient search and data structures and only uses `QCompleter` to hold a small (and sorted) list of already found candidates. There's an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html) which does somewhat similar thing so it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though the first suggestion (setting sort on qcomplete) dint showed improvement, i will definitely start working on the example referenced by you.

Comment: That dint help much. User has to manually press Ctrl + E to pop up the suggestions. I tried to remove the shortcut only, and popped up qcomplete every time a key is pressed, sadly the performance is not a improvement.

Comment: The point is not to follow the example to the letter - of course you don't have to introduce the Ctrl + E shortcut for the completion to pop up. The point is to intercept the moment when the completer is normally called by the widget and 1) do efficient search for the completion string - you would have to implement that using whatever algorithm/data structures appropriate; 2) fill the standard `QCompleter`'s model with pre-found candidates and let is do its work on the small dataset with which it shows acceptable performance.

Comment: It's not at all that easy to implement efficient search among tens of thousands of strings. There are different algorithms and data structures which can be employed for that - for example, [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree) or [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) just to name a few. But you'd have to either look up ready C++ implementations or write your own versions from examples.

Comment: Ok thanks i will get it a try, since i am a newbie to qt, i am finding it a little hard doing these stuff.